# Google spreadsheet. How to update cell value depending on which cell was edited

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Let's say I have 3 columns each containing the same price, but in a different currency. I need to update the other two depending on which column has been updated.
I presume I would need a base value in one of these currencies and somehow update this value when editing one of the cells in each column, then update the other columns by calculating the values using that base value.
Is this possible to do in google spreadsheets? As far as I know each cell may contain only a single formula.

Comment: The onEdit() function may help...  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: See also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know each cell may contain only a single formula.

True. Furthermore, your cells can't contain formulas at all, given that you're going to edit the values manually.

Let me suggest you another approach to your situation:

```
[A]      [B]         [C]               [D]                 [E]
VALUE    CURRENCY    VALUE IN EUROS    VALUE IN DOLLARS    VALUE IN POUNDS
 1,00    Euros        1,00              1,29                0,79
10,00    Dollars      7,72             10,00                6,12
```

You'd have two editable columns (`value` and `currency`), and three automatically calculated columns. The `currency` column could even have a dropdown combo to select each value instead of having to type it (to do so, just define a validation rule for the column).

The formulas for these calculated columns would be quite easy. For example:

```
[C2]: IF(OR(A2="";B2="");"";A2*IF(B2="Euros";1;IF(B2="Dollars";0,772;1,26)))
```

Something like that. Of course, the conversion values should be moved to configuration cells, so they can be easily changed without editing the formula.

---

If you want/need to keep your sheet with only the 3 columns you mentioned, then what you need can't be done with simple formulas. You'll need to write a script which detects the edit event on a cell and updates the other two. I'm sure that it **can** be done, I'm just not so familiar with the Spreadsheets API to tell you how, but it must not be quite difficult.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a button on the sheet. Whenever you click it, a script will execute to perform what you need.

Comment: Someone with 8 reputation probably doesn't know how to do that.  Also, wouldn't an automatic script based on onEdit() be more efficient?